# How does conservation of momentum apply to this billiard ball problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque

> A billiard ball, initially at rest, is given a sharp impulse by a cue. The cue is held horizontally a distance $h$ above the centerline as in the figure below. The ball leaves the cue with a speed $V$ and, because of its "forward English," eventually acquires a final speed of $9V/7$. Show that $h = 4R/5$, where $R$ is the radius of the ball.
>
> [image: figure of ball getting hit by cue]

I've attempted the problem by using the conservation of angular momentum about the point of contact, but I can't seem to get the right answer.

To be more clear, I'm having trouble figuring out how I can apply the conservation of angular momentum (if applicable).

Comment: Can you explain more fully what you've tried and (conceptually) what you don't understand?  That way it will be more in line with the site's [homework-like problem policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/).

Comment: For sure, I just did that.

Comment: So where is your analysis so far? since you say you have just added it.

Comment: You need to finish the phrase "a final speed of".

Comment: @MarkH Sorry about that. It's fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the cue acts with a force $F$ on the ball and that the friction is negligible during this short time interval $\Delta t$.

The translational accerelation of the ball is given by $F = ma$. The force $F$ also produces a torque $Fh = I\alpha$ on the point of contact.

Since the ball is initially at rest, we have
$$mhv = Fh\Delta t = I\alpha\Delta t = I\omega_0$$
where $\omega_0$ is the angular velocity immediately after the cue hits the ball.

The ball is now rolling while slipping forward (hence the "forward English") until the friction with the ground slows down the rotation so that the ball rolls without slipping, i.e. until the angular velocity is $\frac{9v}{7R}$.

As in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/467541/44978) we conclude that total angular momentum is still conserved so
$$mRv+mhv = mRv+I\omega_0 = mR\left(\frac97v\right)+I\left(\frac{9v}{7R}\right)$$

which after using $I = \frac25mR^2$ yields $h = \frac45R$.

Comment: Why is angular momentum conserved around the center though? Isn't friction exerting a torque?

Comment: @SidhantRajadnya Yeah, that part was unclear to me as well but look here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/467541/44978 It is shown that the total angular momentum around the center and around a point on the ground is conserved as the friction becomes an internal force.