# Conservation of Angular Momentum in case of rolling with sliding

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Say a ball is given an initial velocity $v_i$ on a rough horizontal surface in the positive $x$-direction. The surface provides frictional force $f$ which applies a torque $fr$ (where $r$ is the radius of the ball). Due to the frictional force, there is an acceleration $a$ in the negative $x$-direction and an angular acceleration $\alpha$ in the clockwise direction. After some time $t$, at the instantaneous axis of rotation $O$, the translational velocity becomes equal to $r\omega_f$, i.e., $v_f = r\omega_f$ and the ball starts pure rolling.

We get $v_f$ and $\omega_f$ from the equations:

$v_f = v_i - at$ and $\omega_f = \alpha t$

We can calculate $\alpha$ from the torque equation: $fr = I_\textrm{com} \alpha$

I have been taught that during this entire process from $t=0$ to $t=t$, the angular momentum of the ball is conserved. Therefore, conserving angular momentum about the instantaneous axis of rotation $O$, we can write, $$mv_ir=I_\textrm{com}\omega_f + mv_fr$$

My question:

How are we able to conserve the angular momentum, even though there is an external torque $fr$ acting on the ball (i.e., $\tau_{\textrm{ext}} \neq 0$)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466039/is-angular-momentum-conserved-in-impure-rolling/467541#467541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not conserving the angular momentum about the center of mass . We are conserving the angular momentum  about  the instantaneous axis of rotation  , which is about the point of contact and hence we can apply conservation of angular momentum as torque due to friction about point of contact is 0.

Comment: That is because the friction force exerts no torque about the point of contact.

Comment: @R.W.Bird yes... that is what I meant . I will include this in my answer. thanks.